# Intents wont work with Discord.py enabled both trough website and code

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am making discord bot that removes certain role if u remove certain emoji reaction from message. I enabled my intents both trough discord developers website and code and I still get error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles', this is my code

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
   
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        role = get(guild.roles, id = 861745493049868319)
        await member.remove_roles(role)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

client.run()
```

anyone knows what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't have to do with intents. Its because you are using `fetch_guild` which does **not** populate with members, thus your `.get_member` call is returning None.

Always try to avoid using the fetch methods and try to use the `get_x` equal.

Also, this behavior is noted on `fetch_guild`